# How to solve this error using Apache Tika in Android studio?

Tags: android, apache-tika

I found some error using **Apache Tika**. I tried to find a solution but I couldn't solve this error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK resources/grib1/ecmwf/cen085/local_table_2_version_001
    File1: /Users/hihello/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tika/tika-app/1.13/e0649edcc26563f59f7fc37f223d83f4988d5566/tika-app-1.13.jar
    File2: /Users/hihello/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/edu.ucar/grib/4.5.5/cfe552910e9a8d57ce71134796abb281a74ead16/grib-4.5.5.jar
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031395/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformresourceswithmergejavaresfordebug)

Comment: I tried that solution, but unfortunately, it doesn't work. I think that solution is not my solution.

Comment: Why are you including the standalone Tika App jar in your build? Why aren't you adding the regular Tika dependencies?

Comment: How can I add regular Tika dependencies?