# apache poi-ooxml 3.15 not allowing me to run Android Project

Tags: java, android-studio, apache-poi

I'm attempting to add Apache POI to my project to create spreadsheets.

I've added the apache poi to my gradle...

```
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.15'
```

Initially this brought up an error "Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithmergejavaResForDebug'." - Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031395/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformresourceswithmergejavaresfordebug)

I added the following to my gradle...

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
```

This now creates the following...

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlSimpleList$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlSimpleList$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.inst2xsd.RussianDollStrategy$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.inst2xsd.util.Type$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.jam.JamUtils$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$3) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl$SchemaTypeLoaderCache$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.CharUtil$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.CodeGenUtil$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.CodeGenUtil$ThreadedReader$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaCodeGenerator$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaResourceManager$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XsbDumper$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.validator.ValidatingXMLInputStream$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xpathgen.XPathGenerator$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/ReferenceResolver;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/XMLEvent;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/XMLInputStream;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/XMLName;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/XMLStreamException;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/utils/NestedThrowable;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/utils/NestedThrowable$Util;
Error:8 errors; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 8.167 secs
Information:162 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I'm not sure how to progress from here? I've attempted to follow the instruction from a few other questions I've seen but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Apache POI will not work on Android out of the box due to various problems that you will run into when using the libraries from Apache POI directly. Android is more strict on what it allows as part of the jar-files.

There are some projects that make it possible to use most of Apache POI on Android:

1. https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx (for Android 5) and https://github.com/andruhon/AndroidReadXLSX (for Android 4), both are currently still based on Apache POI 3.12
2. https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/ (for Android 5, maintained by me), which can be more easily recompiled with newer versions of POI, e.g. it uses 3.15 currently