# Dependency Conflicts in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Here's my `build.gradle`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.btcxwalletdemo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        jumboMode = true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.3-android'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.5.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.3'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
    compile 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    compile 'org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.14.5'
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.58.0.0'
    compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0'
    compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:1.54.0.0'
    compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pg:1.54.0.0'
}
```

I'm getting error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'. More than one file
>   was found with OS independent path
>   'org/spongycastle/x509/CertPathReviewerMessages_de.properties'

I'm getting the error and It won't allow me to run the application until I solve the dependency.

Please help me out this.

Comment: Try commenting    `compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0'`

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031395/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformresourceswithmergejavaresfordebug

Comment: Hey, Did you have got solution for the same error?'org/spongycastle/x509/CertPathReviewerMessages_de.properties'

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the specified file in your PackagingOptions/excludes block